# How to change value in a 2 dimensional alist

Tags: emacs, elisp

Suppose, we have the following alist:

```
(setq sql-connection-alist
      '((local
         (sql-product 'mysql)
         (sql-server "localhost")
         (sql-user "user")
         (sql-password "")
         (sql-database "")
         (sql-port 3306))))
```

And the function:

```
(defun sql-local ()
  "Connect to the local MySQL server"
  (interactive "sWhat database do you want to connect? ")
  (let ((symbol (intern key)))
    ;here I want to set the database field for sql-database = symbol
     (sql-connect-preset symbol)))
```

If I did it in Perl, it would be something like this:

```
my %databases = (
    "local" => {
         "sql-product" => "mysql",
         "sql-server" => "localhost",
         "sql-user" => "user",
         "sql-password" => "",
         "sql-database" => "",
         "sql-port" => "3306",
    },
);

$databases{local}->{sql-database} = $symbol;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure whether you find what you want in `sql-connection-alist` use:

```lisp
(let ((place (assoc 'sql-database (assoc 'local sql-connection-alist))))
  (when (consp place)
    (setcdr place (list symbol))))
```

otherwise you could also use:

```lisp
(setcdr (assoc 'sql-database (assoc 'local sql-connection-alist)) (list symbol))
```